# BroadcastReceiver won't call onReceive method

Tags: java, android, xml, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make an app that blocks calls with ITelephony depending on which radio button is pressed in my main activity. However, my onReceive method never gets called and therefore, doesn't block the call.

Here is my class that extends BroadcastReceiver

```
   public class CallBlocking extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final int MODE_WORLD_READABLE = 1;
        private String mPhoneNumber;
        private String mCallerName;
        private SharedPreferences mPreferences;


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mPreferences", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            String blockMode = mPreferences.getString("mode", "not retrieved");
            if (!blockMode.equals("cancel")) {
                Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
                String phoneState = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if ((phoneState.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {
                    mPhoneNumber = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    if (blockMode.equals("all")) {
                        disconnect(context);
                    } else if (blockMode.equals("unsaved")) {
                        mCallerName = getContactName( mPhoneNumber, context);
                        if((mCallerName == null) || (mCallerName.length() < 2))
                            disconnect(context);
                        else if (blockMode.equals("list"))
                        {
                           if(CallBlockerFragment.sBlockedList.contains(new BlockedList(mPhoneNumber)))
                              disconnect(context);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
        private void disconnect(Context context) {
            ITelephony telephonyService;
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
                telephonyService.endCall();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String getContactName(String phoneNumber, Context context) {
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
            String callerName = "?";
            String data = null;
            ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor findContact = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

            try {
                if (findContact != null && findContact.getCount() > 0) {
                    findContact.moveToNext();
                    data = findContact.getString((findContact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(findContact != null)
                    findContact.close();
            }

            return data;
        }

    }
```

and here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="edu.uwp.sean.pike.csci323.callblocker">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/quevedo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".CallBlockerActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddToBlockedListActivity">
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".CallBlockerActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BlockedListActivity">
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".CallBlockerActivity">
        </activity>
        <receiver  android:name=".CallBlocking">
            <intent-filter  android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Why isn't it calling the onReceive method?

Comment: Are you sure your method is not being called? Did you try to add a print to the logcat at the entry point to check it?

Comment: You need to have a PhoneStateListener in order to receive those callbacks, so maybe the onReceive is running but not doing anything because there is no listener?

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you would like to achieve is to listen for phone state changes...please check out the following link [Listen to Change of Phone State State - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537403/listen-to-change-of-phone-state-state-android)