# How to know if the calling intent is running in background or foreground?

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I am using calling phone intent in Android as follows:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(phone_num.trim())));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

The package name is `com.android.incallui`. I want to know if the calling GUI is running in background or foreground. Hence, I make a function `checkcallingGUI`, it will return true if the calling GUI is running in the foreground, and false if the calling phone is running in the background. Is it possible to check it? Thank all

Comment: what do you mean by `calling GUI`? your activity?

Comment: You could track your activity state callbacks and just have a boolean set in your `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods of the GUI activity

Comment: @marmor: No. The calling GUI intent of phone. For example, when I dial a phone number, then I press the home button, the calling GUI is still running, but it is running in background.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register a `listener` on `TelephonyManager` call states (`IDLE`, `OFFHOOK`, `RINGING`), and use the last received state to know if a call is currently in progress or not.

Use this method to register a listener:
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int))

Read about possible stated and their meaning here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE

And see complete code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537914/819355

**EDIT**

You can use the KeyguardManager service to check if the device is currently locked/secure, see this method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isKeyguardLocked()

If i'm not mistaken, if the call-state is not IDLE, and the keyguard is enabled, you'll get the full screen UI, if not, it should be in the background.

Try something like this:

```
KeyguardManager kg = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if (kg.isKeyguardLocked()) {
   // If telephony-state is also not IDLE, then the call UI should be full screen.
}
```

Comment: I tried it before but it does not tell me the calling GUI in background or foreground.